# How to execute "Insert" query on a SQLite Database from a Batch file knowing the location of the File Database?

Tags: windows, sqlite, batch-file

Our application uses a SQLite Database on Windows placed in the location

> C:\Users\Administrator\dbFile.db

We want to insert a row to the table from a Batch file

```
INSERT INTO "Table1" ("Property1","Property2","Property3") VALUES("Value1","Value2","Value3");
```

How to write the batch file to run this query on the Sqlite Database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file with the commands as you presented, in this example I make it `myfile.txt`:

```
INSERT INTO "Table1" ("Property1","Property2","Property3") VALUES("Value1","Value2","Value3");
```

then execute is as:

```
sqlite dbFile.db < myfile.txt
```

Comment: where can i get sqlite3 executable? is there any way to do it without the sqlite3 executable?

Comment: or just `sqlite`

Comment: Do I need to package either sqlite.exe/sqlite3.exe as part of my setup if I need to update the sqlite DB on a remote system from an installer that calls my batch script?